# @Value with map of sets

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I have the following code:

```java
@Value("#{${optional.currencies}}") 
private Map<Account, Set<String>> mapAccountAndCurrencies= null;
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList' to required type 'java.util.Map'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList' to required type 'java.util.Map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1235)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList' to required type 'java.util.Map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73)
    ... 71 more
```

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {BatchTestConfiguration.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
public class BatchTest {

}
```

and my applicatin-test.properties:

```
optional.currencies={}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, can you please post how you set the property ```optional.currencies```? Thanks!

Comment: thanks @KajHejer . I've edited my post

Comment: that is working for me without any issues @sewey

Comment: @NicoVanBelle still have the same issue. My actual batch runs fine though (with a similar application.properties). I get this error only when running my BatchTest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `optional.currencies` to be a map of sets, like

```
optional.currencies={'account1': {'USD','GBP'}, 'account2': {'USD','NOK'}}
```

Can you please let me know if this solves your issue?

Comment: Hi, what if I want it to be empty ? This is a param that will be needed only in test environment. But in Live environment, this property must not be set;

Comment: It might work to just not set it in live environment and set it empty as defaultvalue using a ```:```, see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-defaults. In this case I think you can just leave it empty after the ```:```.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
@Value("#{${optional.currencies:{null:null}}}") 
private Map<Account, Set<String>> mapAccountAndCurrencies= null;
```